# sudo apt-get upgrade - The package sublime-text needs to be reinstalled?

Tags: apt, sublime-text

How can I fix the sublime-text error below:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

Error:

```
E: The package sublime-text needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I get the same error even I tried to remove it:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove sublime-text
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package sublime-text needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to do `sudo apt-get purge sublime-text`. Then do `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: @GautamVashisht thanks for the comment. Got it fixed at last!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of this error, type the following commands(one-by-one) in your terminal :-

`sudo apt-get purge sublime-text`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

`sudo apt-get update`

After that `sudo apt-get upgrade` will work fine and will not show errors.

To install **Sublime Text**, download its .deb package for Ubuntu/Debian from [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/3). Then install Sublime Text from that .deb package either using **dpkg** or **GDebi Package Installer**(recommended).