# The package sublime-text needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, sublime-text

I'm trying to remove sublime 3 but I have an error:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove sublime-text-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package sublime-text needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I tried this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848476/sudo-apt-get-upgrade-the-package-sublime-text-needs-to-be-reinstalled) but still getting the same error:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge sublime-text
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package sublime-text needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: The package sublime-text needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Any ideas?

I'm ok Kubuntu 16.10.

**EDIT:**

I interrupted sublime installation process, could it be causing this bug?

First:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3

Sublime Text 3 Installer: the package in this PPA downloads and installs the latest Sublime Text 3 beta builds.

For more info, see: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/07/sublime-text-3-ubuntu-ppa-now-available.html
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/sublime-text-3
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmp35ijqt87/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmp35ijqt87/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key C2518248EEA14886: public key "Launchpad VLC" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
OK
```

Then:

```
$ sudo apt-get update

Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                                                                                    
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-2/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                                                                               
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease [102 kB]                                                                                                      
Hit:4 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                                                                 
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                                                   
Hit:6 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x yakkety InRelease                                                                    
Hit:7 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease                                                                                                                      
Get:8 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:9 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports InRelease                                                                                                            
Fetched 204 kB in 2min 17s (1,486 B/s)                                                                                                                                           
Reading package lists... Done
```

Then:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

But it was too slow so I ended it.

**EDIT 2:**

```
$ dpkg -l *sublime* | grep -i sublime
iHR sublime-text           3126             amd64        (no description available)
iHR sublime-text-installer 3126-2~webupd8~1 all          (no description available)
```

Comment: do `dpkg --configure -a` to fix any issue.

Comment: @George thanks. have tried that but still the same `E: The package sublime-text needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

Comment: Edit your question to include the output from `terminal` of `dpkg -l *sublime* | grep -i sublime`. Start any new comments directed at me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Answer (score 1):

try these steps

- Configure interrupted packages `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
- fix broken dependencies `sudo apt --fix-broken install`
- remove unneeded packages `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove`
- uninstall sublime-text `sudo apt-get purge sublime-text`

That should do it.

Comment: thanks. have tried that but still the same `E: The package sublime-text needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

Comment: when i do `sudo dpkg --configure -a` nothing happens.

Comment: I see.  Can you please tell me how did you install sublime text?

Answer (score 0):

If these package don't appear in Synaptic (it seems that you have both -2 and -3 ppas installed), you'll find the .deb files here...

https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/sublime-text-3/+files/sublime-text-installer_3126-2~webupd8~1_all.deb

https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/sublime-text-2/+files/sublime-text_2.0.2-1~webupd8~3_all.deb

... just try the first link first.

Comment: what shud i do with them? click to install them?

Comment: Since you aborted the first install attempt, and you haven't been able to solve the problem with @sirajussalekin good suggestions, try a reinstall using the first link that I gave you. Then retry the `dpkg -l *sublime* | grep -i sublime` command, and the status should change from `iHR` to `ii` meaning that it's fully installed now. Then you also have to decide if you want/need both -2 and -3 ppas defined.

Comment: have tried with `dpkg -l *sublime* | grep -i sublime` after installing the first link but still seeing `ii` as the status...

Comment: also, why the first .deb only has 9.3kb?

Comment: 'cause that's all it is. It is a beta installer, so it may only contain a minimal install. I don't use sublime, so I can't say for sure. I did download it, and it properly starts the gdebi installer on my system.

Comment: ps: `ii` is the proper status of a properly installed software package. Show me the full current output of the dpkg -l command again.

Comment: i got it fixed now following this http://askubuntu.com/questions/88371/apt-synaptic-needs-to-reinstall-package-but-cant-find-the-archive-for-it

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all sublime-text
```